# Power dissipation of synchrononous buck converter cannot be reduced with gate drivers?

Tags: integrated-circuit, power-electronics, switch-mode-power-supply, dc-dc-converter, buck

For this project, I had to want to reduce the power dissipation (< 2 mW) when the Rload is 54 Ω. These are the two circuits that I have employed.

[image]

[image]

When I sweep the pwm frequency vs Pdiss (power dissipation of the buck converter), without the gate driver, I have the following:

[image]

When I sweep it including the gate drivers, I obtain:
[image]

From those two plots with out gate drivers, I see that including gate drivers I increase the power dissipation by increasing switching frequency, but when excluding gate drivers, the power dissipation will decrease with increasing switching frequency. Hence, why is that?

Furthermore, is there a solution to solve this? Maybe decreasing the gate driver area?

The output voltage of the syncrhonous buck converter is 1.2 V and all other parameters are the same in both the circuits.

Comment: (Why power the "non-overlapping generator" from \$V_{DDD}\$?)

Comment: Because the non-overlapping generator is on transistor level, which means supply voltage is needed to supply all the NMOS and PMOS transistors. All the NMOS and PMOS transistors in the non-overlapping generator are specified for 2 V, but lower is also possible.